# Set Fingerprint as the quality of the password policy on Android

Tags: android, android-settings, android-securityexception

Is there a way on Android for a device admin application to only allow fingerprints as the password policy of the device?

Answer (score 0):

Not in standard Android, because few Android devices have fingerprint sensors. Please contact your device manufacturer for instructions regarding their devices' fingerprint sensors.